# Get most popular tags from mysql normalized tables

Tags: php, mysql, tagging

I'm building my own tag system for a forum I'm making. Everything is working perfectly, but I am trying to echo a list of the most popular tags but I can't find which query to use..

My tables look like this:

[image]

I need a list of the 20 most popular tags, so the tag_names of which the tag_id appear the most in the article_tag_xref table. Anyone who has an idea what the query should look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag_name, COUNT(article_id) AS cnt
FROM Article_Tag_Xref AS a
INNER JOIN Tag AS t ON a.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY t.tag_id, t.tag_name
ORDER BY COUNT(article_id) DESC LIMIT 20
```

`COUNT(article_id)` returns the number of appearances of each `tag_ig` in the `Article_Tag_Xref` table. Thus, order by this count in descending order and applying a `LIMIT 20` returns the 20 most popular `tag_ig` values.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as I want! One more question: if I had three colums in my article_tag_xref table (article_id, story_id, discussion_id)  instead of one (article_id), how would I need to change that query to get the most popular tags in all three those columns? So the most used tags in the articles, discussions and stories (article_id, discussion_id and story_id)?

Comment: @SenneVandenputte So you want to count separately for each of these fields?

Comment: No, together. So instead of showing the most popular tags in one section of my site, I want to show the most popular tags on the whole website. So I don't only want to look at the article_id column but also the discussion_id and story_id column that are added to the article_tag_xref table.  COUNT(article_id) should then become a COUNT of three different columns instead of one. Don't know if that's even possible

Comment: @SenneVandenputte Say you have entries like `tag_id, article_id, story_id, discussion_id` = `(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3)`. What would be the count in this case?

Comment: Such an entry is not possible, because when a member posts for example a new story, then the entry will be (given he tags it with tag_id = 1), (1,0,1,0), so every row in the table will have a tag_id and one of three post id's. I needed three columns because a story and discussion can have the same id. So what I need is to show the tags that are used the most on the website, in all 3 sections. The idea is actually very simple, but I know it sounds complex..

Comment: @SenneVandenputte Do you get the desired result if you do a `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(article_id)`?

Comment: @SenneVandenputte Can you try posting a new question with sample data and required result?

Comment: I just did! Hope it will be more clear now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554805/how-to-get-the-overall-most-popular-tags-from-normalized-tables

Answer (score 0):

The following should work out for you, as you only asked about the tag_names without their count.

```
SELECT tag_name 
FROM Tag
WHERE tag_id IN ( SELECT tag_id, COUNT(article_id)
                  FROM Article_Tag_Xref
                  GROUP BY tag_id
                  ORDER BY COUNT(article_id) DESC
                  LIMIT 20)
```

The subquery returns the top 20 `tag_ids` and their count.